# handing the 404 error page in zf2 modules

Tags: php, templates, module, zend-framework2

I have two modules:

```
->Patient
->Doctor
```

`project/` points to `Patient` module and `project/doctor` points to the `Doctor` module.

So when I type the `project/forgotpass`, it should point to the 404 error page from the `Patient` module, but it points me to the `Doctor` 404 error page.

How can I manage to point to the respective 404 error pages.

In the `Patient` module config:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/patient' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'error/404'      => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'    => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    )
)
```

And in the `Doctor` module config:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/doctor' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'error/404'     => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'   => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    )
)
```

Is it okay to have separate 404 pages, or should I call respective module 404 error page. My issue here is that the `Patient` module is calling the `Doctor` 404 error page.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the templates to different ones:

```
'not_found_template'       => 'error/patient/404',
'exception_template'       => 'error/patient/index',
```

And use them in the template map:

```
'error/patient/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
'error/patient/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
```

Comment: is this your global config or module config?

Answer (score 0):

The config arrays from the different modules are on bootstrap all merged into one application wide config array. This means that keys with the same name will be overwritten by the last loaded file.

You can see the merged config results by doing:

```
$config = $serviceManager->get('Config');
```

The `layout/doctor` and `layout/patient` are unique names and thus they will not be overwritten. But the key `error/404` is not unique so it will be overwritten.

You probably load the `Doctor` module after the `Patient` module so the `error/404` from your doctor module will be shown.

If you load in the reverse order it will show you the `error/404` from your Patient module (try it :) ).

---

So all this merging of configs means you can define the `not_found_template` and `exception_template` under the `view_manager` key only once:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index'
)
```

Error pages are usually defined once in a `Application` module and used for all modules throughout the whole ZF2 application.

Comment: @user3929758 Did you read my answer? Do you understand how it works now with setting templates in the config?